# How can I solve sturm-liouville equation for k=n*pi?

Tags: python, differential-equations, eigenvalue, boundary

I try t solve a simple Sturm-Liouville problem:

y'' + k**2 * y = 0;
y(0) = y(1) = 0

I write our equation as a first-order system and implement its right-hand side evaluation:

y1' = y2;
y2' = -k**2 * y1

```
def fun(x, y, p):  
    k = p[0]
    return np.vstack((y[1], -k**2 * y[0]))
```

Note that parameters p are passed as a vector (with one element in our case).

Implement the boundary conditions:

```
def bc(ya, yb, p):
    k = p[0]
    return np.array([ya[0], yb[0], ya[1] - k])
```

Set up the initial mesh and guess for y. We aim to find the solution for k = 2 * pi, to achieve that we set values of y to approximately follow sin(2 * pi * x).
**(but how can I solve the equaion for k=n*pi (n=1,2,3..n) instead of k = 2 * pi)**

```
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 5)
y = np.zeros((2, x.size))
y[0, 1] = 1
y[0, 3] = -1
```

Run the solver with 6 as an initial guess for k.

```
sol = solve_bvp(fun, bc, x, y, p=[6])
```

We see that the found k is approximately correct:

```
sol.p[0]
```

6.28329460046
And, finally, plot the solution to see the anticipated sinusoid:

```
x_plot = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
y_plot = sol.sol(x_plot)[0]
plt.plot(x_plot, y_plot)
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.show()
```

This solution is only one k values, what should be the code for k=1,2,3,..n.(n is a integer, maybe 10) can you help me please?

Comment: You need to start with an initial guess that is close to the solution, that is, that has the appropriate number of oscillations and with a `k` that is also close to the actual value. Failure of being sufficiently close leads to the solution spontaneously switching to a neighboring value of `k`.

Comment: can you help me with code, please? I am new coder.

Comment: isn't it just a wave equation? use the exact solution instead?

Comment: It is not wave equation. I need a every eigenvalue and eigenfunction